# check for each month, how many customers have bought a product within 7 days

Tags: r, dplyr

i am a beginner in programming. I have a table in which each rows is an order (variables : id_customer and date). I want to set a function that calculates for each month the number of customers that have made an order within 7 days. How can i do this ?

This is the output of my data :

| id_customer | jour_commande |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 12-05-2021 |
| 10 | 13-07-2021 |
| 18 | 17-07-2021 |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRDKu.png)

I have tried this, it's only for time difference between two orders for each customers:

```
data  %>%
  arrange(id_customer,jour_Commande) %>% 
  mutate(diff = jour_Commande - lag(jour_Commande)) %>% 
  group_by(id_customer,jour_Commande)
```

the first customer it goes well but for the others i have negative numbers.

can someone help me on this ?

thanks in advance !

Comment: Please provide an example of your data set in order to help you, by pasting the output of `dput(head(mydf))`, `mydf` being whatever name you have for your data frame.

Comment: Yes @Phil, i've just edited my post :)

Comment: When you say "the number of customers that have made an order within 7 days", within 7 days of what? Given your example provided, what would be your expected output?

Comment: excuse by bad english, i mean that the customer ordered another product after <= 7 days.  My expected output should be a table that provides for each month the number of customers that have bought a product in 7 days or less that 7 days after bying the previous one. Hope i am clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempt. I'm using the storms data set from the dplyr package as a substitute because it's too much work to type in all the data in the screenshot.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

mydat <- storms %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(paste(year, month, day, sep = "-"))) %>%
  select(name, status, date) %>%
  distinct(name, status, .keep_all = TRUE)

mydat

# A tibble: 513 x 3
   name     status              date      
   <chr>    <chr>               <date>    
 1 Amy      tropical depression 1975-06-27
 2 Amy      tropical storm      1975-06-29
 3 Caroline tropical depression 1975-08-24
 4 Caroline tropical storm      1975-08-29
 5 Caroline hurricane           1975-08-30
 6 Doris    tropical storm      1975-08-29
 7 Doris    hurricane           1975-08-31
 8 Belle    tropical depression 1976-08-06
 9 Belle    tropical storm      1976-08-07
10 Belle    hurricane           1976-08-07
# ... with 503 more rows

mydat %>% 
  arrange(name, date) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(diff = date - lag(date),
         within_7 = if_else(diff <= 7, TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(!is.na(within_7)) %>%
  count(within_7)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  within_7     n
  <lgl>    <int>
1 FALSE       50
2 TRUE       249
```

EDIT: Looping through month-by-month

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
mydat %>% 
  mutate(month = month(date),
         year = year(date)) %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(count_data = map(data, ~ .x %>%
                            arrange(name, date) %>% 
                            group_by(name) %>%
                            mutate(diff = date - lag(date),
                                   within_7 = if_else(diff <= 7, TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
                            ungroup() %>%
                            filter(!is.na(within_7)) %>%
                            count(within_7))) %>%
  unnest(count_data) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 98 x 5
   month  year data             within_7     n
   <dbl> <dbl> <list>           <lgl>    <int>
 1     6  1975 <tibble [2 x 3]> TRUE         1
 2     8  1975 <tibble [5 x 3]> TRUE         3
 3     8  1976 <tibble [3 x 3]> TRUE         2
 4     9  1976 <tibble [3 x 3]> TRUE         2
 5     8  1977 <tibble [3 x 3]> TRUE         2
 6     9  1977 <tibble [3 x 3]> TRUE         2
 7    10  1977 <tibble [3 x 3]> TRUE         2
 8     7  1978 <tibble [2 x 3]> TRUE         1
 9     8  1978 <tibble [5 x 3]> TRUE         3
10    10  1978 <tibble [2 x 3]> TRUE         1
# ... with 88 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you @Phil !  As i want to count the number of customer giving this condition per month, i used your suggestion :                                                                                `mydat %>% 
  arrange(name, date) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(diff = date - lag(date),
         within_7 = if_else(diff <= 7, TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(!is.na(within_7))`

Comment: And added a column for month, i want to creeate a loop function that goes throught the month column and if TRUE is observed in the "within_7" it givers +1 to the counter. So that i can store the exact number of customers per month. how can i dot this ? Thank you for your help !!

Comment: I edited my answer to provide an example where I iterate through the steps within each month/year.

Comment: oh nice, i didn't know we can do this with tidyr and purr packages. Nice :)  I have done this to see if the total customer is the same as the number provided by TRUE and FALSE condition when i tried your condition :                                                                                                                                ``test_nb_com <- corders_time %>% group_by(annee, Mois) %>% summarise(nb_client=n()) 
``

Comment: And it's not the same. Is this normal ?

Comment: i think i got it : the number is not the same because there is the na filter but if the condition is not approved, it should be FALSE instead of getting na, i don't understand why we have na here.

Comment: these are clients that didn't make another order , they have just done only one  so there's not another next date :) Thank you very much for your help @Phil